# How to write text in Lock Screen?

Tags: android, lockscreen

I have searched in SO to find a way to write some text in lock Screen like so many apps in Google Play.
There are some similar questions about this but unfortunately I haven't find a clear answer which works for me. I have tested this on my Galaxy S5 :

```
String message = "This is a test";
Settings.System.putString(context.getContentResolver(),
        Settings.System.NEXT_ALARM_FORMATTED, message);
```

(I have used the right permission for that)

but it doesn't work for me(or maybe I don't know where and how to use it in my code) Is there anyone to give me a clear answer about how to write some text in lock screen?

Comment: have you declare  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS"/> in your manifest?

Comment: yes, I have declare that.

Comment: Have you made any progress on this? I also send text to the lock screen using the same method you are using, which does work perfectly on a few other phones (including other Samsung models). For some reason, there is something special about the S5 lock screen. Placing this call in a new thread didn't help and I've played with the phone settings as well (still no luck). Just can't get this to work. I can't tell our users to install a third party lock screen too.